# spring cloud config client config refresh not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

When using spring cloud config client , I try to update my app config via update application.properites file. But it dose not work.

What i already try : update config file , and commit to git;

Dose anyone know what is going on ?
I try to test it it result in controller String value like below:

```
@Value("${my-name}")
private String name;
```

And i already add @RefreshScope in my client side config;
Did I  miss something ?

Comment: did you refresh the scope by doing a post request to `/refresh`

Comment: Yes, and i was learning from here ; http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally work work why.
It did not work because I put @RefreshScope in a wrong place.
If we want it to work work , we need to place @RefreshScope to the Configuration Class that we want to update value .
So , in my case , I need to place it to the Controller class that using this bean value.

```
@RefreshScope
public class ClientController {
    @Value("${my-name}")
    private String name;
}
```